# Border texture for a View

Tags: android, view, border

Is there any way to set border texture for `LinearLayout` or any other `View`? I can't just set an image as the background because of different screen sizes.

Here is the sample of the texture I'm talking about:

[image]

I tried to use *Nine-patch*, but it stretches the white lines that are supposed to be repeated.

*Screenshot from Draw 9-patch tool:*

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `shape` drawable like this:

```
<shape android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#FAFAD2" />           
    <stroke android:width="1sp" android:color="#000000"
        android:dashWidth="7sp" android:dashGap="5sp" />
</shape>
```

and this will result you something like this:

[image]

You can change color, width, border etc according to your requirements.

Comment: I don't need solid color as background. It has to be a dark texture from the sample I linked above.

Comment: Then just make it the way you need it. This is _the_ only elegant solution for that problem.

Comment: But is it possible to set a texture as shape background? Or at least make it transparent?

Comment: Yay! I set `<solid android:color="#00000000" />` and it worked. Thanks.

Found the answer here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5646944/how-to-set-shapes-opacity