# Setting opacity to a shape

Tags: android

I have a shape like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<stroke
  android:width="1dp"
  android:color="#d5dce5" />

<corners android:radius="5dp" />

<gradient
  android:angle="270"
  android:centerColor="#e7eff8"
  android:endColor="#e9f0f8"
  android:startColor="#e0e8f1" />


</shape>
```

Which I include in my layout like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

....

  <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/rectangle"
        android:layout_width="276dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/rectangle"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">
  </LinearLayout>

....

</LinearLayout>
```

How can I set the opacity of this shape to 50 % ? Is it possible?

Comment: see this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5646944/how-to-set-shapes-opacity

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how hex colors work:

```
# + Transparent + Transparent + Red + Red + Green + Green + Blue + Blue.
```

So lets take your center color: android:centerColor="#e7eff8"

50 % of FF = 7F.

End results = #7fe7eff8"

Answer (score 2):

You will need to use RGBA color instead of RGB:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RGBA_color_space

Where the first 2 are Alpha, 2nd 2 are Red, 3rd 2 are Green, 4th 2 are Blue