# How can I make the borders and the colors?

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I'm learning at XML and I made something like this:

```
              <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:background="@drawable/color1fp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Blah Blah"
                android:textColor="#1c469b"
                android:textSize="30sp"
                android:textStyle="italic" />
```

Where color1fp.xml is:

```
 <item android:state_pressed="true" >
    <shape>
        <solid
            android:color="#f7cd00" />
        <stroke
            android:width="1dp"
            android:color="#F1F1F1" />
        <corners
            android:radius="3dp" />
        <padding
            android:left="10dp"
            android:top="10dp"
            android:right="10dp"
            android:bottom="10dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item>
    <shape>
        <gradient
            android:startColor="#f7cd00"
            android:endColor="#F1F1F1"
            android:angle="270" />
        <stroke
            android:width="1dp"
            android:color="#F1F1F1" />
        <corners
            android:radius="4dp" />
        <padding
            android:left="10dp"
            android:top="10dp"
            android:right="10dp"
            android:bottom="10dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

The result will be as a picture:

[image: pic 1]

My questions are:

1. how can I make the borders look like [image: this]
2. How can I make the two colors (yellow and white) transparent?

Comment: I believe this is what you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5646944/how-to-set-shapes-opacity
And instead of "make transparent" I think you mean just reduce the opacity, correct?

Comment: It worked, thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

To accomplish the first point add this to your < shape > label:

```
<corners
 android:bottomRightRadius="10dp"
 android:bottomLeftRadius="10dp"
 android:topLeftRadius="10dp"
 android:topRightRadius="10dp"/>
```

To acompplish the second point you have to add alpha values to your hexa code for example, your yellow color is #f7cd00 and you can make it transparent as I said by adding 2 digits at the start: #AAf7cd00.
You can see the values for transparency in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17239853/5658915)

Comment: Please mark it as the correct answer if it helps you!.